# dalekjs error on running any tests scripts on Ubuntu

Tags: dalekjs

Hi i've been using a lot of dalekjs in my companies mac, but when I try it in ubuntu I get this error when running any scripts

```
~/Desktop/test $ dalek test.js
Running tests
Running Browser: PhantomJS
>> ERROR: SyntaxError: Unexpected token E
~/Desktop/test $
```

I have followed all the instructions properly in installing dalekjs the same way I have installed it in my mac and this is the first time I get this kind of error. Can you guys tell me if I missed installing something to make dalekjs run? Thanks!

Comment: I've the same problem, but on Windows7

Comment: @JanBaer how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Could you please give me the node version you´re using, as well as the version of the dalek-cli tools?

I believe that this error might came in with a PR I added.

Comment: @SebastianGolasch my node version is v0.10.25, DalekJS CLI Tools Version is 0.0.4

Comment: @SebastianGolasch My node version is v.10.13 and also 0.0.4

Comment: @JanBaer check out my answer. I figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, I think it was the installation process is where I went wrong. I installed everything globally and locally.

So this time I uninstalled all dalekjs packages locally and globally and then followed this process

```
sudo npm install dalek-cli -g

sudo npm install dalekjs
```

and it worked out just fine for me

Comment: I just had a chat with someone over IRC with exactly the same problem.
He needed to do an `npm cache clean` before, because the invalid package got stored in npms cache.

Comment: i'll take note of that in the future if I encounter problems. thanks!

Comment: by the way I still have problems when installing packages with dalekjs in Ubuntu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408618/dalek-browser-chrome-fails-installing-everytime @SebastianGolasch hope you can help me out