# dalek-browser-chrome fails installing everytime

Tags: npm, phantomjs, dalekjs

on my Ubuntu. I tried installing the browser plugin from chrome just as the website says to execute.

```
npm install dalek-browser-chrome --save-dev
```

problem is I get this error when running the command.

```
> dalek-browser-chrome@0.0.9 install /home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome
> node install.js

Chromedriver installation failed Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/monece/tmp/chromedriver'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:642:18)
    at mkdir (/home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/install.js:156:8)
    at Promise._successFn (/home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/install.js:177:7)
    at Promise._withInput (/home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/node_modules/kew/kew.js:248:25)
    at Promise._chainPromise (/home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/node_modules/kew/kew.js:290:13)
    at Promise.then (/home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/node_modules/kew/kew.js:154:13)
    at /home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/install.js:175:23
    at /home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/node_modules/npmconf/npmconf.js:76:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-chrome/node_modules/npmconf/npmconf.js:75:13
npm ERR! dalek-browser-chrome@0.0.9 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dalek-browser-chrome@0.0.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the dalek-browser-chrome package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls dalek-browser-chrome
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "dalek-browser-chrome" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/monece/Desktop/dalekjs/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

p.s. I also tried using sudo npm install and it still doesnt not work

Comment: I´ve seen this one or two times before on other systems.
The problem is that the `sudo` can't be dispatched to the fs functions I´m using to get the the `Chromedriver`file out of the temp folder.
One option would be to fetch the download directly into the node_modules, but that would cause other problems.

I´ll be investigating an alternative fetching mechanism & come back to you for testing purposes when it is ready.

Comment: okay thanks sir! I will be waiting because I would really like to create scripts at home but I can't as of the moment